# Hot to prevent recalculating window sizes in vim?

Tags: vim

I show what happens step-by-step to explain the case:

This is my layout:

[image]

After I run `:vs new` to create new file in the separate window:

[image]

Now you can see that the leftmost window with directory tree is unexpectedly expanded by several columns. And and I close the `new` buffer by `^Wc` or `:close` the rightmost window expanding again!

[image]

What's going on? Is there any ways to "fix"/"stick" window sizes. Windows like water - they are constantly resizing(

Comment: What about `set noea`?

Comment: Much better!) You can post it an answer. What about set windows height/width equally horizontally or vertically not at the same time? For example: `^W=` (affects only horizontal), `^W=|` (affects only vertical).

Comment: Check `:h eadirection`, it is probably what you want.

Comment: You can also use `:set winfixwidth winfixheight` to fix height and width of a window. See the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option [`equalalways`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalalways%27) when set, makes Vim equalize the windows sizes when a window is closed or opened. You can switch it off by using

```
set noea
```

or you can change its behaviour by adding the [`eadirection`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27eadirection%27) option to control in which direction windows should be equalized.

Comment: I don't know vim good. Please, could you explain how to assign v/h equation of windows to different keys..

Comment: I see that your question [was already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390855/how-to-make-windows-equal-horizontally-or-vertically-by-shortcuts). If you are looking for a way how to do the mapping, I would recommend quite nice [Learn Vimscript the hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html) or [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) on [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com). Only instead of `<C-W>` (ie. `^W`) I would probably use `<Leader>`.