# How to make windows equal horizontally or vertically by shortcuts?

Tags: vim

I am looking for the way to make Vim windows equal only vertically or horizontally, not both at the same time.
For example, I want `^W=` to affect only window width and `^W=|` to affect only its height. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **@rburny** who suggest the appropriate commands. So the final result is:

```
nmap <c-w>== :set ead=ver ea noea<CR> " set windows equal vertically (^W, =, =)
nmap <c-w>=- :set ead=hor ea noea<CR> " set windows equal horizontally (^W, =, -)
```

If you want to set windows equally both, just press `^W=` and wait for a moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't use `equalalways` option, since you want to do such operations manually. In this case, you can hack `equalalways` to do what you want:

```
" make all windows the same height
:set ead=ver ea noea
" make all windows the same width
:set ead=hor ea noea
```

What these commands do is basically:

- set preferred direction for `equalalways` (vertical / horizontal)
- enable & disable `equalalways`, which causes the windows in a current tab to be made equal in chosen direction

Obviously, you can map these commands to any key sequence.